# Ubuntu 18.04, network interface enp9s0 disappears suddenly

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, network-manager, netplan

I am new to ubuntu, and I am using ubuntu 18.04 server. I configured the network interface enp9s0 with static address using netplan, and everything was working fine. Suddenly the the network interface is down and ping results fail. I check the ifconfig results and the interface enp9s0 disappeared. I tried the netplan apply command but still doesn't solve the problem.

The interfaces returns to normal when I reboot the ubuntu, and after a while it disappears again.

I attached 
    Network configuration file and error log
   [image: network config]
   [image: error log]

Please help, it is really disrupting my services.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Liban! Welcome to askUbuntu! Please post terminal outputs as plain text, and not as pictures. This makes it easier and faster to read your post.

Comment: Does it help to run `modprobe -r atl1c; modprobe atl1c`?